# Trying to pass through a query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

hey everyone i am having a problem with trying to run a query on a database i have set up. I am setting up a vehicle rental database and i am trying to run a query to see which vehicle is available for renting between two dates. i have two tables that are involved in the query a vehicle booking and a vehicle database. i can see which vehicle is available when i run my query but it only is showing the results in regards to the booking database. (also duplicate values are showing up) is there a way in which i can pass the data to show me the results base off all the vehicles in the vehicles table. Sorry if that's a bit confusing any tips is much appreciated.

```
 SELECT Vehicles.[Vehicle ID]
    ,Vehicles.Make
    ,Vehicles.Model
    ,Vehicles.[Type of Vehicle]
    ,Vehicles.Year
    ,Vehicles.Colour
    ,Vehicles.[Price/ Per Day]
    ,Vehicles.[Out of Service]
    ,Booking.End_Rent_Date
    ,Booking.Start_Rent_Date
FROM Vehicles
INNER JOIN Booking
    ON Vehicles.[Vehicle ID] = Booking.[Vehicle ID]
WHERE End_Rent_Date < [enter start date]
    OR [enter end date] < Start_Rent_Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicles
WHERE Vehicles.vehicle_id NOT IN (
        SELECT Vehicle.vehicle_id
        FROM Booking
        WHERE (
                start_date BETWEEN booking.enter_start_date
                    AND booking.enter_end_date
                )
            OR (
                end_date BETWEEN booking.enter_start_date
                    AND booking.enter_end_date
                )
        )
```

You have to get the set of cars that are rented between these dates and exclude them from your query, thats why you use `not in`.

The query is right, you just need to edit the start/end date part.

Comment: Thanks i keep getting an error though is that just becuase i need to create a parameter where it says enter start date

Comment: ohh yess you should set the start and end date parameters!test the query first using the dbms you are using.then you should take the date parameters from the program you are using

Comment: i keep getting an error saying missing ),], in the query expression Vehicle.vehicle_id NOT IN " all the way to the end of it. any idea what may be the problem with it

Comment: yess i forgot another ) bracket at the end( for the not in)

Comment: okay thanks so much guys the query seems to be working for me but the problem is now its asking me 5 different parameters... one for the vehicle.vehicle_ID and then start date and enter start date and the same with the returning date.. any idea how to get rid of those parameters and only keep the enter start date and enter return date ??

Comment: as i understand , you first havve to enter dummy data to your tables in your database and test the query based on the data.After you enter data you have to replace the start_date and end_date with real dates such as '2016-12-12' or 2016/01/01' based on the date format

Comment: SELECT *
FROM Vehicles
WHERE (((Vehicles.Vehicle_ID) Not In (SELECT Vehicles.vehicle_ID
        FROM Booking
        WHERE (
                [Enter start date] BETWEEN booking.start_rent_date
                    AND booking.end_rent_date
                )
            OR (
                [Enter end date] BETWEEN booking.end_rent_date
                    AND booking.end_rent_date
                )
        )));

Comment: That is what i have at the minute and no results is being shown any idea where i might be gone wrong for it not to be working... i am buessing the .booking mist relalate back to the names for start and end date in the booking table would that be correct

Comment: any idea what the problem might be

Answer (score 0):

-To show all available vehicle:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   vehicles x1 
WHERE  x1.vehicle_id NOT IN 
   ( 
          SELECT vehicle_id 
          FROM   booking x2 
          WHERE  ( 
                        enter_start_date BETWEEN x2.start_rent_date AND    
x2.end_rent_date) 
          OR     ( 
                        enter_end_date BETWEEN x2.start_rent_date AND    
x2.end_rent_date)
```

Comment: @willium what do you mean by x1 and x2 am i suppose to keep that in my query

Comment: i keep getting a missing item post when i try and run the query